# Laracasts/flash not showing in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, flash-message

I have recently upgraded my project from Laravel 5.1 to 5.4. Everything is working fine except for flash messages which are not displaying. I have perform the following checks to make sure I am not doing something wrong:

1. RouteServiceProvider.php

The web middleware group is added automatically to my routes by mapWebRoutes function

```
+--------+----------+-----+--------+------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI | Name   | Action                                   | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+-----+---------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /   |        | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index| web,auth     |
```

2. Kernel.php

Below is the content of the middleware groups in Kernel.php

```
 'web' => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            ],
```

3. flash() is placed before redirects

   flash()->success('Bob stone Added Successfully');
   $target_location = 'cia_agent/' . $agent_id .'/profile';
   return redirect($target_location);

Just one 302 reponse is returned in Network in Chrome developer tool.

The above code works in Laravel 5.1, what are my missing here?

Comment: Which version of the package are you using? have you tried updating the flash package to the latest version?

Comment: I am using laracasts/flash 3.0

Comment: There was a change to view partial used to display the messages. If you had published and used it, you need to manually change it. https://github.com/laracasts/flash/blob/master/src/views/message.blade.php This is from the release changelog https://github.com/laracasts/flash/releases/tag/3.0.0

Comment: I do have the correct view. that is done with `@include('flash::message')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging, I found the solution. In /resources/views/vendor/flash/message.blade.php, I had the following code which was working for Laravel 5.1

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))
    @if (Session::has('flash_notification.overlay'))
        @include('flash::modal', ['modalClass' => 'flash-modal', 'title' => Session::get('flash_notification.title'), 'body' => Session::get('flash_notification.message')])
    @else
        <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

            {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
@endif
```

But since there is been a change with Laracasts/flash view partial used to display messages, I put the new code in the file:

```
@foreach ((array) session('flash_notification') as $message)
    @if ($message['overlay'])
        @include('flash::modal', [
            'modalClass' => 'flash-modal',
            'title'      => $message['title'],
            'body'       => $message['message']
        ])
    @else
        <div class="alert
                    alert-{{ $message['level'] }}
                    {{ $message['important'] ? 'alert-important' : '' }}"
             role="alert"
                >
            @if ($message['important'])
                <button type="button"
                        class="close"
                        data-dismiss="alert"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        >&times;</button>
            @endif

            {!! $message['message'] !!}
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach

{{ session()->forget('flash_notification') }}
```

It's working perfectly now.